# Kivy Python - Affecting Buttons Inside a Different Function

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to change the attribute of a button inside of a different method. This is what I am currently using:

```
def _finish_init(self, dt):
    self.ids.grid_1.cols = 5

    def callfun(self, *args):
        self.ChangePic()

    # Creating a variable to use to determine if the buttons should be editable
    binded = 0

    # Loop to make 15 different buttons on screen
    for x in range(15):
        self.buttons.append(Button())
        self.ids.grid_1.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
        self.buttons[x].background_normal = 'YOUTUBE.png'
        self.buttons[x].background_down = 'opacity.png'
        self.buttons[x].bind(on_release=partial(self.HoldButtonNum, x))


        # Make the button switch screens to input from calling the function above
        if edit_mode is True:
            self.buttons[x].bind(on_release=partial(self.SwitchScreenInput, x))

def ChangePic(self, *args):
        _finish_init().buttons[1].background_normal = 'folder.png'
```

When ChangePic is called I get the error:

> NameError: name '_finish_init' is not defined

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both functions are members of a class, you would need to use

```
self._finish_init()...
```

Comment: When using  self._finish_init(dt=1).buttons[1].background_normal = 'folder.png'  I am getting: " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'buttons'"

Comment: The '_finish_init()' function is returning 'None'. Looking at the function I don't see any return statements.